# Desafio palindromeRearranging codesignal

Tags: javascript, array, string, objeto

Aclaración: Es mí primera pregunta, disculpen. Olvidé decir el objetivo del challenge  Me pasan un string ('aabbcfc') el algoritmo debe retornar true si al reorganizar las letras se puede formar un palindromo. En este caso retornaría true porque puedo formarlo ('abcfcba')

Estoy practicando javascript en codesignal y quiero empezar a trabajar sobre mi propio código. Escribí esta solución y pasa 18/20 test, pero no me da información de los últimos errores. Pienso que puede ser algo de eficiencia. ¿Sugerencias para mejorarlo?

Parti de la idea de que un palindromo sólo se puede crear si la cantidad de cada letra es par, salvo una que puede ubicarse justo en la mitad.

Gracias por sus sugerencias.

```
function palindromeRearranging(inputString) {
    const letters = [...inputString]
    const counter = {}
    let unique = 0
    let moreOneOdd = false
    
    letters.forEach((element) => counter.hasOwnProperty(element)? counter[element]++: counter[element] = 1)
    const values = Object.values(counter)

    values.forEach((value) => value===1?unique++:unique)
    values.forEach((value) => value%2!==0 && value !==1?moreOneOdd=true:moreOneOdd)
    if(unique>1 || moreOneOdd === true){
      return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el objetivo de la función? ¿Solamente decir si la palabra/frase es palíndroma? Pienso que deberías replantear un poco el método para saber si lo es, ¿qué pasa cuando se colocan acentos? Por ejemplo con la frase **Isaac no ronca así** la cual es palíndroma pero claramente no obtendrá dos `í` o dos `I`.

Comment: Disculpa, ahí edite la pregunta. Pequeño detalle el que olvidé. Me dan un string de letras 'aabbccddf' debo retornar true si se puede organizar como palindromo. En este caso se podría ('abcdfdcba'). En este otro ('aabbbccc') retornaría false. Acabo de darme cuenta que 'aabbbcc' podría formar un palindromo 'acbbbca' pero mí función retornaría false.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer en una sola línea comparando la cadena original contra:

- Convirtiendo en arreglo, caracter por caracter con [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- Invirtiendo el arreglo con [.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)
- Convirtiendo nuevamente en cadena con [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Esto va a resultar en misma cadena, pero invertida:

```
function checkPalindrome(inputString) {
    return (inputString == inputString.split('').reverse().join(''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En una solución para saber si es palíndromo se pide en la mayoría de las veces que se ignoren los espacios y puede que también se pida que se ignoren los acentos de las palabras y si está en Mayúsculas o minúsculas.

1. `str => [...str].reverse().join('')` pone el string de reversa
2. `normalize("NFD")` lo que hace es separar las letras de los acentos
3. `replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '')` simplemente quita los acentos (ya separados de las letras)
4. `replace(/\s/g, '')` quitará todos los espacios
5. `toLowerCase()` pondrá el texto en minúsculas

```js
const reverseString = str => [...str].reverse().join('');

function isPalindrome(str) {
  str = str.normalize("NFD").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '').toLowerCase()
  return reverseString(str) === str;

}

console.log(isPalindrome("Anita lava la tina"));
console.log(isPalindrome("Definitivamente no es palíndromo"));
console.log(isPalindrome("RAtáR"));
```

Answer (score 0):

gracias a los que respondieron. Primero me disculpo porque me falto explicar el challenge. Pequeño detalle. Cuando lo hice encontre el error. Por ejemplo, mi función retornaba false para este caso ('aaabbcc') cuando deberia ser true, dado que puede quedar así ('bcaaacb')

Mi funcion parte de la idea de que todas las letras debian repetirse un numero par de veces, salvo una que podia no repetirse (1).

```
values.forEach((value) => value===1?unique++:unique)
    values.forEach((value) => value%2!==0 && value !==1?moreOneOdd=true:moreOneOdd
```

Pero esa excepcion podia estar un numero impar de veces, no solo estar una vez. Asi que lo corregi y pasó el challenge.

```
    values.forEach((value) => value%2 !== 0?unique++:unique)
    values.forEach((value) => value%2!==0 && unique > 1?
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifiqué el final de tu función, donde haces la comprobación de los valores impares, con el objetivo de simplificar un poco el código.

Lo que hago es filtrar los valores imapres (del arreglo values), y cuento la cantidad que hay, si hay 1 o menos entonces es palindromo y retorna true, caso contrario no lo es y retornará false.

```
function palindromeRearranging(inputString) {
    const letters = [...inputString];
    const counter = {};
    
    letters.forEach((element) => counter.hasOwnProperty(element) ? counter[element]++ : counter[element] = 1);
        
    const values = Object.values(counter);
    
    //Modifiqué tu código de acá en adelante:
    let impares = values.filter(e => e % 2 !== 0);

    if(impares.length <= 1) {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```